# ¿Cómo quitar comillas de algunos elemento de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente lista en python:

```
[43, '1', '1', '3', '11', 1.00, "['24466500', '5650000']", 100000000.00, 'AS6', "['92100000', '40000000']"]
```

necesito quitar las comillas dobles de los elementos tipo `list` de la lista que está arriba, es decir, que la lista me quede de la siguiente manera:

```
[43, '1', '1', '3', '11', 1.00, ['24466500', '5650000'], 100000000.00, 'AS6', ['92100000', '40000000']]
```

Traté con `replace()` pero no me funciona en este caso.

Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes quitar las comillas dobles porque no forman parte del objeto (de la cadena) en realidad. Solo son agregadas a la hora de imprimir o reproducir el objeto `str` para que sea identificado como una cadena por el usuario. Lo que necesitas es convertir esa cadena que representa una lista en una lista en si misma. Esto seria mas sencillo antes de construir esta lista, ya que al ser una lista mixta hay que filtrar aquellos objetos que son cadenas y que son representaciones validas de una lista.

Puedes usar una combinación de regex y [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) para hacer lo que deseas:

```
import ast
import re


lista = [43, '1', '1', '3', '11', 1.00, "['24466500', '5650000']", 100000000.00, 'AS6', "['92100000', '40000000']"]

patt = re.compile(r"\[.*\]")
res = [ast.literal_eval(e) if isinstance(e, str) and patt.fullmatch(e) else e for e in lista]

print(res)
```

**Salida:**

```
[43, '1', '1', '3', '11', 1.0, ['24466500', '5650000'], 100000000.0, 'AS6', ['92100000', '40000000']]
```

Por cada elemento de la lista filtramos aquellos que sean cadenas con `isinstance`. Aquellos que lo sean pasan un segundo filtro para saber si son o no representaciones de listas,  para lo que se usa la expresión regular. Aquellos elementos que cumplen ambas condiciones son pasados a `ast.literal_eval` que evalúa la cadena y retorna el objeto Python adecuado (una lista).

`ast.literal_eval` a diferencia de `eval` es segura ante la inyección de código ya que las expresiones que evalúa exclusivamente se limitan a strings, números, tuplas, listas, diccionarios, booleanos y None.

La expresión regular es un poco burda, puede perfeccionarse para descartar posibles string que empezando por "[" y terminando con "]" no son en realidad listas Python válidas.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma muy sencilla, tal vez no la más segura es haciendo esto:

```
lista = [43, '1', '1', '3', '11', 1.00, "['24466500', '5650000']", 100000000.00, 'AS6', "['92100000', '40000000']"]

final = [e.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'","").split(",") if isinstance(e, str) and e[0] == '[' else e  for e in lista ]
```

La salida:

```
print(final)
[43, '1', '1', '3', '11', 1.0, ['24466500', ' 5650000'], 100000000.0, 'AS6', ['92100000', ' 40000000']]
```

Es una simple comprensión de listas

- Verificamos cada elemento de la lista y lo retornamos
- Si el es una instancia de la clase `str` y el primer carácter es `[` entonces:

  - Quitamos mediante varios [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) los caracteres `[]"`
  - Y por último mediante un [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) armamos una lista.

Comment: Funciona bien, gracias @Patricio. Perdona mi ignorancia, pero ¿porqué dices que no es la más segura?

Comment: Simplemente por que basamos la búsqueda de las listas en un único carácter `[`, que además suponemos debe ser el primero de la cadena , si tienes algo así `" [..."` no lo reconocería. Una solución mas segura sería usar expresiones regulares para ubicar estas listas,pero es algo más complejo y si tienes seguridad acerca del formato no tendría mucho sentido. Si te fijas la solución de FJSevilla va en ese sentido.